# What happens to backlink authority after 301 redirect removed

Tags: 301-redirect, backlinks

I configured 301 redirect to another URL, thus moving all backlink authority to the new URL.

The question is if I disable 301 redirect and start serving content from the old location do I gain backlink authority back to the old URL from the SEO perspective? How long does it take? What happens to the authority of the page which the original page was initially redirecting to?

Comment: Do you have a compelling reason to reverse the 301?

Comment: @Kannan That was a hypothetical question, I negotiated some 301 redirects to my own resource with 3d party websites, so I am wondering what happens if 3dparty website owner disables it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From an SEO standpoint, such reversals send mixed signals to search engines. You can never predict delays. You can be almost sure of ranking fluctuations at least in the short term. Below is a quote from Moz.
(Reference: [Can You Reverse A 301 Redirect?](https://moz.com/blog/can-you-reverse-a-301-redirect))

> 301-redirects take time to process, and reversing them (or changing
> signals in any major way) often takes even more time. Be prepared for
> those delays, and prepare your stakeholders. You may see ranking flux
> during this time period. Most of the time, it will pass fairly
> quickly, but reversals tend to get messy.